# External hard drive encryption using Disk Utility

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, encryption

I'm looking to encrypt an new external hard drive via disk utility (Mac OS Extended | Journaled Encrypted) as shown on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvfrIyS1K04&frags=pl%2Cwn.

Will this drive only be able to be read on Max OS? If i need to access files through a Windows system am I out of luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are out of luck accessing it on a Windows machine. The macOS Extended Journaled format is unreadable by Windows.

You can share the drive by formatting with FAT32, however, as detailed in this [PCWorld web page](https://www.pcworld.com/article/250431/how_to_share_an_external_drive_between_a_mac_and_a_pc.html).